# IF ELSE problem COMMAND BATCH

Tags: scripting, batch-file, command, windows-server

I have problem about IF ELSE in Command Batch script...

In Notepad:
Code:

```
:CHECKACCOUNT
if /I "%user%"=="insertusername" ( GOTO :ACCOUNT ) ELSE ( GOTO :CHECKPASSACCT )

:CHECKPASSACCT
if /I "%pass%"=="insertpassword" ( GOTO :ACCOUNT ) ELSE ( GOTO :COUNTER )
```

In COMMAND:
Code:

> ( was unexpected at this time.

FULL Script Code:

```
@echo off

::SETTINGS:::::::::::::::::::::::
set filetxt =userpass.txt
set log=logfile.log
set timer=900
::set default = true
::set user = 0
::set pass = 0
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:STARTER
ECHO.>>%log%
ECHO ========START========>>%log%
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set n=
Set _InputFile=%filetxt%
For /F "tokens=*" %%I IN (%_InputFile%) DO (
Set /a n+=1
Set acct!n!=%%I
)
set router_ip=%acct1%
set user=%acct2%
set pass=%acct3%
GOTO :CHECKFILE1


:CHECKFILE1
CLS
IF EXIST curl.exe ( GOTO :CHECKFILE2 ) else (
ECHO ERROR: curl.exe was not found.>>%log%
ECHO ERROR: curl.exe was not found.
ECHO.
ECHO.
GOTO :PAUSEEXIT
)

:CHECKFILE2
CLS
IF EXIST sleep.exe ( GOTO :CHECKACCOUNT ) else (
ECHO ERROR: sleep.exe was not found.>>%log%
ECHO ERROR: sleep.exe was not found.
ECHO.
ECHO.
GOTO :PAUSEEXIT
)

:CHECKACCOUNT
if /I "%user%"=="insertusername" GOTO ACCOUNT
GOTO CHECKPASSACCT

:CHECKPASSACCT
if /I "%pass%"=="insertpassword" GOTO ACCOUNT
GOTO COUNTER

:ACCOUNT
CLS
::if %default% = true ( GOTO :COUNTER ) ELSE (
ECHO To edit/change USERNAME and PASSWORD... Please type: OPTION
ECHO.
SET /P user="Please enter the username of your Router:"
IF /I %user%==OPTION ( Goto :EDITBAT )
CLS
ECHO To edit/change USERNAME and PASSWORD... Please type: OPTION
ECHO.
SET /P pass="Please enter the password of your Router:"
IF /I %pass%==OPTION ( Goto :EDITBAT )
CLS
set /a i = 1
GOTO :CHECKACCOUNT
::)

:EDITBAT
start /WAIT notepad %filetxt%
set router_ip=%acct1%
set user=%acct2%
set pass=%acct3%
GOTO :CHECKACCOUNT

:COUNTER
IF %i%==0 ( GOTO :RESETROUTER ) ELSE (
ECHO WAIT %i% seconds...
sleep 1
set /a i = i - 1
CLS
GOTO :COUNTER
)


:RESETROUTER
CLS
ECHO READY to RESET....
ECHO Preparing....
sleep 2

sleep 2
CLS
ECHO Processing....
sleep 5

sleep 2
CLS
ECHO Success....
sleep 5
set /a i = %timer%
CLS
GOTO :COUNTER

:PAUSEEXIT
PAUSE

:EXIT
ECHO.>>%log%
ECHO ========END OF LOG FILE========>>%log%
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simplify this down to:

```
:CHECKACCOUNT
if /I "%user%"=="insertusername" GOTO ACCOUNT
GOTO CHECKPASSACCT

:CHECKPASSACCT
if /I "%pass%"=="insertpassword" GOTO ACCOUNT
GOTO COUNTER
```

The `ELSE` statements aren't needed.  Since the `IF` block will jump somewhere else, placing the second `GOTO` on the next line or in an `ELSE` block should be equivalent.

Also, you need the leading colon when defining a `GOTO` target but not when referring to the target name inside the `GOTO` statement itself.

Comment: Actually, if there's no code in between the two blocks then you can simplify it further and remove the `GOTO CHECKPASSACCT` line and the `:CHECKPASSACCT` line.

Comment: When you say it still doesn't work, what error is it giving you and what line does the error occur on?  It can't be the same error, since the offending `(` no longer exists.

Comment: Also, within your `:COUNTER` block, you probably want to put `%i%` in double-quotes since you can enter that block before `i` is ever set.

Comment: Adding quotation marks will resolve the syntax error in that line, but your logic is still broken.  The variable `i` needs to be initialized to some valid starting value so that you will never hit the `:COUNTER` block before you explicitly set it.  Editing the batch file and re-testing in the same shell window can cause variables like `i` to be re-used between runs, so try adding commands like `set i=` at the top of the batch file to clear out any old data before the script executes (this can hide uninitialized variable problems like this one).

Comment: aws... its working now.. look like i missing "set i=" Thanks bta for helping me... :)

Answer (score 18):

Your error as seen comes from wrong formatting. Don't put it all on 1 line. Instead use this:

```
if /I "%user%"=="insertusername" (
     GOTO :ACCOUNT 
) ELSE (
     GOTO :CHECKPASSACCT 
)
```

The deeper, underlying reason is: `goto :somewhere` command needs to be terminated by a newline.

Comment: If prefer @pipitas anser over @bta as it is simpler and does not side-step the question of `else` behavior.  Both answers are good though.  Just a side note, but I've noticed odd behavior calling `goto` within a loop where it branches to a line directly above an `if` statement.  In those cases, oddly, placing an `echo nul>nul` or something similar between the destination and the `if` statement works like a charm.

Comment: A bit late, but the description is wrong. The syntax is correct, it's absolutly valid to use `if "1"=="1" (goto :label1) ELSE (goto :label2)`. `goto` doesn't need a newline

Answer (score 3):

The problem has nothing to do with the shown code!

The problem is at

```
:COUNTER
IF %i%==0 ( GOTO :RESETROUTER ) ELSE (
```

As the variable `i` isn't defined, the line will be expanded to

```
IF ==0 ( GOTO :RESETROUTER ) ELSE (
```

That is an invalid expression.

To find such simple syntax fails, you should enable debugging with `ECHO ON`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the parentheses. You're basically telling the system
"if %user% is insertusername (" and it's asking "what is the '(' supposed to do?"

Comment: WRONG, the first parenthesis block have to be used here to build a command block. Without the parenthesis the ELSE can't be parsed (it will be part of the `goto` command) and the `IF` failed for `false` conditions